# Imperial Levels keep resetting on construction time

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have purchased two Imperial levels and started the 30 hour wait.

Three times so far, the first level has reset from the 22 hour mark back to a 30 hour wait.  Anyone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bug that will require a reinstall!  Sorry!!!!!!!  You can try restoring from a backup, but to my knowledge, the success rate there has been low. You can try contacting Disney customer support for help, as they provide the support for the game.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the bug people are experiencing with regard to the holiday decorations resetting themselves at random.  It might be some sort of timing issue . . .